# Android EventBus - hasSubscriberForEvent() always returns true

Tags: android, event-bus

How this is possible that EventBus method hasSubscriberForEvent() returns true when there is no subscriber for an event?
In my app I use EventBus to communicate between two Services. I also use hasSubscriberForEvent() to check if Service with Subscriber is working. It used to work fine. Now it isn't and I have no idea why.

I created new dummy event which does not have Subscriber for test purpose and this always returns true:

```
L.d(TAG, "hasSubscriberForDummyEvent? " + eventBus.hasSubscriberForEvent(DummyEvent.class));
```

Has anyone face similar issue with EventBus? I use 3.2.0 version from greenrobot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out that subscribing on event type Object was causing this behaviour. Which now seems to be obvious.